# Is it possible to "pile up" headers in a sectioned listview or linearlayout when users scroll

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview, android-linearlayout

I have an idea but I don't know if it can be realized on android.

Here is the idea:
I have a form with several sections for users to fill in. For now the form is in a LinearLayout which is enclosed in a ScrollView. The form has three sections: step1, step2, and step3. What I want to do is when the user scrolls down, the sections collapse and the headers remain on the top of the ScrollView. I created a couple illustration below to help describe what I want:

Before Scrolling:
[screenshot http://img15.hostingpics.net/pics/421226951.png](http://img15.hostingpics.net/pics/421226951.png)

After Scrolling:
[image: screenshot]
<sub>(source: [hostingpics.net](http://img15.hostingpics.net/pics/909525512.png))</sub>

Thanks for your response!

Comment: Yes! it is totally possible :)

Comment: White on white is always nice to see :D

Comment: @WarrenFaith To be fair, the image hosting site has a dark gray background color. I imported the images.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some basic code snippets from google devs. Roman Nurik [showed some sticky headers](https://plus.google.com/u/0/113735310430199015092/posts/1Sb549FvpJt) for a ListView. Check the second solution in the provided video, it is not exactly what you are looking for but it is close.

You could also check the [Synchronized Scrolling Library](https://github.com/xrigau/Synchronized-Scrolling/tree/master/XaviRigau-SynchronizedScrolling) which provides a [sample app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.xrigau.syncscrolling.samples) in the market. You should check how he has implemented the last sample "similar to Gmail app" which looks like what you described.

Comment: Thanks! Though that's not exactly what I need but it's close. It seems that it only requires a little tweak.

Comment: Feel free to share your solution with code as an answer and mark it, too. That would help others, too.